# write an Algorithm for a Function that calculates average of 3 numbers and then average is called by a sub procedure to display the average

Tags: vb.net

I have no problem programming this in VB.net as it is rather simple. I understand functions and sub procedures and how they work. Im just having some trouble writing it as an algorithm.

Below is an algorithm ive writen for it if everything had to take place in a sub procedure:

~Start
Display "Enter first number"
Enter num1
Display "Enter second number"
Enter num2
Display "Enter third number"
Enter num3

~process
Average = (num1 + num2 + num3) / 3

~output
Display Average

I would like to know how i should write the algorithm if the calculations are done in the function and the answer displayed by sub-procedure.
Do i have to state function and procedure name?
Do i have indicate if variables are ByVal or ByRef?

I have looked rather thoroughly for a solution or atleast a pointer in the right direction.

Comment: Please read [ask] and take the [tour].  We are not going to do your homework for you

Comment: I don't think you are using any standard for your algorithm writing. Just do what ever you like. Pass the values as normal parameter to function and sub.

Answer (score 0):

You could use just a Flowchart, since its the easiest and (at least for me) more clearly option for small algorithms.

There a lot of free software....just look for flowchart software.

[Here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flowchart) you have Info about it and under "See Also" section, you can find other options to "represent" an algorithm.

ULM is also an option.

About `ByRef, ByVal, Subprocedures` etc, you are describing an algorithm. The description is language-agnostic. You use ByVal and ByRef in VB, but not in other languages...
You are not describing how to implement the algortihm in a given language, that is just writing the code. You are taking the code, abstracting the process so that ANYONE could write in ANY language the same functionality.

Comment: Thanks for clearing up the ByVal, ByRef. I understand that algorithms should not contain any language specific syntax. Although i was not sure about them as my experience with other languages at this point are minimal. I would much rather use a flow chart for a small bit of code like this, i agree. I got this question in a test a few months back at college. I scored 8 out of 12 for the question.  The method of algorithm was not specified. So i used a D&C(Divide and conquer) approach. Although this is a very small bit of code it was the only method i  use to seperate the two sections clearly.

Comment: Thanks for the help atleast i know the problem doesnt ly there. I will have a look at the link and research a bit further from there. Thanks again for the help